# Preface/Appendix but for the middle of a document

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a document with several numbered chapters. If I added extra information at the end of the document, I would call it an Appendix. However, what if I added a non-numbered chapter (for extra information) between two numbered chapters?

I was thinking of calling it something like an "intermission" or an "aside", but I wondered if there is a specific term for this.

Comment: There was, years ago, a term for a sort of index/table of contents stuck in the middle of a book/magazine/catalog, but I can't recall it.

Comment: I think the generalization is "affix"

Comment: Supplement. OED - 1b. A part added to complete or extend a literary work or any written account or document;

Comment: I have seen (perhaps in French-language documents) chapters numbered like this... 1, 2, 3, 3bis, 4, 5

Comment: A boxout or sidebar holds briefer information, but I guess this is intending something of chapter-length, when it would be less appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely thinking of an [**insert**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insert#h2):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : something that is inserted *especially* : written or printed material inserted (as between the leaves of a book)

As for *leaves of a book*, it's from this sense of [*leaf*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leaf):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2** : something suggestive of a leaf: such as
>   **a** : a part of a book or folded sheet containing a page on each side

Although *inserts* are often loose and not bound to the book itself, they can also be permanently attached. An example of such an *insert* is a series of photographs of somebody that's placed between chapters in the middle of a biography.

Even though a photographic insert can be used, it would not normally be referenced *as* an insert in a table of contents. Instead, the individual photographs would be referenced as illustrations or figures, or even by the title of the insert, without using the noun itself. However, different publishers have different guidelines for such things.

---

While [*supplement*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supplement), as suggested in a comment under the question, is possible, that's most often used to describe errata or revisions:

> **2** : a part added to or issued as a continuation of a book or periodical to correct errors or make additions

If it's something that's an intended part of an original publication, it would not normally be considered a *supplement*.

Comment: I well remember reading the colour supplements included with especially Sunday newspapers. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supplement) has merely 'an extra part that is added to a book or newspaper
_advertising/literary supplement_'

Answer (score 0):

How about **interlude**? from Cambridge:

> **[interlude](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interlude)**: a short period when a situation or activity is different from what comes before and after it